# Android service only starts in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, service, android-service, android-service-binding

I have created a Service that manages XMPP connection. My application needs to receive XMPP messages periodically. Everything seems to work as expected, but only while the phone is plugged in to Android Studio and I run the app in debug mode. When I unplug the phone, or even if it is  plugged in but I start the app from the phone and not from the AS, the service doesn't seem to start...

I made sure that my service is declared correctly in the manifest:

```
<service
  android:name=".xmpp.MyService"
  android:enabled="true" />
```

where .xmpp is a sub-package in my main package.

Here is my service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static ConnectivityManager cm;
    public static MyXMPP xmpp;
    private static String LOG_TAG = "MyService";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (CurrentInfo.getUser() != null) {
            xmpp = MyXMPP.getInstance(MyService.this, getResources().getString(R.string.xmpp_url), CurrentInfo.getUser().getJabberId(), getString(R.string.xmpp_password));
            xmpp.connect("onCreate");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
                              final int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        xmpp.connection.disconnect();
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }
}
```

And I start my service like this:

```
// Start xmpp service here
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

Thanks!